# Failed to set VBR quality on WMV MFT encoder

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I'm using Windows Media Foundation WMV encoder on Win10 64bit. While it can be used to encode correctly, I failed to set VBR quality.

Below is the sample code

```
const PROPERTYKEY MFPKEY_VBRENABLED = { { 0xe48d9459, 0x6abe, 0x4eb5, { 0x92, 0x11, 0x60, 0x8, 0xc, 0x1a, 0xb9, 0x84 } }, 0x14 };      
const PROPERTYKEY MFPKEY_DESIRED_VBRQUALITY = { { 0x6dbdf03b, 0xb05c, 0x4a03, { 0x8e, 0xc1, 0xbb, 0xe6, 0x3d, 0xb1, 0x0c, 0xb4 } }, 0x00 + 25 };          

CLSID* pCLSIDs = NULL;   // Pointer to an array of CLISDs.   UINT32 nCount = 0;      
MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO encoderInfo;      encoderInfo.guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Video;  
encoderInfo.guidSubtype = MFVideoFormat_WMV3;      
HRESULT hr = fpMFTEnum(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER, 0, NULL, &encoderInfo, NULL, &pCLSIDs, &nCount);      
if (FAILED(hr) || (nCount == 0)) {}            ciEncoder.CreateObject(pCLSIDs[0], IID_IMFTransform);      
if (ciEncoder.IsInvalid()) {}          

LComInterface<IPropertyStore> ciPropertyStore; // WMV Encoder codec setting interface      
hr = ciEncoder->QueryInterface(IID_IPropertyStore, (void**)ciPropertyStore.GetAssignablePtrRef()); 

if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {         
    PROPVARIANT  propVal;         
    propVal.vt = VT_BOOL;         
    propVal.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;                  
    hr = ciPropertyStore->SetValue(MFPKEY_VBRENABLED, propVal);                 
    propVal.vt = VT_UI4;         
    propVal.ulVal = 90;         
    hr = ciPropertyStore->SetValue(MFPKEY_DESIRED_VBRQUALITY, propVal);
```

While ciPropertyStore->SetValue(MFPKEY_VBRENABLED, propVal) returns S_OK,
ciPropertyStore->SetValue(MFPKEY_DESIRED_VBRQUALITY, propVal) failed and hr = "The property ID does not match any property supported by the transform"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the root cause: seems I should use MFPKEY_VBRQUALITY instead of MFPKEY_DESIRED_VBRQUALITY

in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 seems MFPKEY_VBRQUALITY is for video, MFPKEY_DESIRED_VBRQUALITY is for audio?